# Start and Stop Stepper Motor using Serial Interface

Tags: arduino

Here's my code for starting a Stepper motor and trying to stop the motor:

```cpp
#include <BasicStepperDriver.h>

#define DIR 34
#define STEP 36
#define ENBL 30

BasicStepperDriver stepper1(10000, DIR, STEP, ENBL);
BasicStepperDriver stepper2(10000, DIR, STEP, ENBL);

bool enableMotor1 = false;
bool enableMotor2 = false;

void rotate1() {
  Serial.println("Rotate start 1");
  stepper1.rotate(360);
  Serial.println("Rotate end 1");
}

void rotate2() {
  Serial.println("Rotate start 2");
  stepper2.rotate(360);
  Serial.println("Rotate end 2");
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper1.enable();
  stepper1.setMicrostep(1);
  stepper1.setRPM(50);
  stepper2.enable();
  stepper2.setMicrostep(1);
  stepper2.setRPM(50);
}

void loop() {
  if(enableMotor1 == true) {
    rotate1();
  } else if(enableMotor2 == true) {
    rotate2();
  }  
  if (Serial.available ()) {
     String first  = Serial.readStringUntil(','); 
     Serial.read(); 
     String second = Serial.readStringUntil(','); 
     if(first == "start"){
        if(second == "1") {
          Serial.println("Starting motor 1");
          enableMotor1 = true;
        }
        if(second == "2") {
          Serial.println("Starting motor 2");
          enableMotor2 = true;
        }
     } else if(first == "stop") {
        if(second == "1") {
          Serial.println("Stopping motor 1");
          enableMotor1 = false;
          stepper1.disable();
        }
        if(second == "2") {
          enableMotor2 = false;
          Serial.println("Stopping motor 1");
          stepper2.disable();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it is not possible to stop the motor through Serial interface. The goal is to have the Stepper motor running until the `stop` command is entered in the serial monitor. What could be wrong in my code?

**This image shows that we can start the motor but can't be stopped:**

[image]

Comment: Did you *speedup* the picture? You send `start,1` instead of `start,1,`, so the second call to `readStringUntil(',')` should incur in a timeout of `1 s.` because no *comma* appears after `1`. Note that this *delay* could potentially disrupt your *stepper* by preventing it from rotating at a constant rate. Removing the *delay* isn't an option either, because with the current *parsing* functionality that you implement you increase the chance of parsing *fragments* of commands rather than the whole thing. Note that you would need an extra `Serial.read()` to account for the extra `,` too.

Comment: Anyway, this looks like an issue that should be easy to *debug*. Did you try: **1.** print the content of `first` and `second` to serial after parsing, what's inside? **2.** repeat the command `start, 1` and see if it is taken again? **3.** send the command `stop, 1` for first and see whether it is taken?

Comment: I wonder why `stop, 1` and `stop, 1,` works?

Comment: interesting, what about other tests =)